# Laravel 6 - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to send `nama` column from `Supplier` table to `Transaction_in` table, but iget this error.

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException Call to
>   undefined relationship [get_transactions_in] on model
>   [App\Transaction_in].

**Transaction_in Model**

```
class Transaction_in extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function get_suppliers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class, 'Supplier_id');
    }
}
```

**Supplier Model**

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function get_transactions_in(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction_in::class);
    }
}
```

**Transaction_in Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $transaction_ins = Transaction_in::with('get_transactions_in')->get();
        return view('transactionsIN.index', compact('transaction_ins', $transaction_ins, 'supplierList'));
    }
```

The foreign key is `Supplier_id` based on `id` from `Supplier` table.

Comment: Why isn't the error message clear? It says that there is no method with that name in your Transaction_in model, which is right, because that method is part of the Supplier model, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called wrong relationship in `with` it should be `get_suppliers` instead of `get_transactions_in`

Transaction_in  Model has `get_suppliers` method so,

```
$transaction_ins = Transaction_in::with('get_suppliers')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your controller code with below

```
public function index()
    {
        $transaction_ins = Transaction_in::with('get_suppliers')->get();
        return view('transactionsIN.index', compact('transaction_ins', $transaction_ins, 'supplierList'));
    }
```

you got an error because there is no relation like "get_transactions_in" in your  Transaction_in model