# Laravel 8.83.26 - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship still cannot resolve

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

```
hello, i have same problem but after change it following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480919/laravel-6-illuminate-database-eloquent-relationnotfoundexception-call-to-undef#new-answer?newreg=d9514acf03b84d9d998451758b15e0c7 still unable to resolve 

class BottleController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data=  Bottle::with('typebottle')->get();
        dd($data);
        //return view('bottle',compact('data'));
    }
}

class Bottle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function typebottle()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(TypeBottle::class,'TypeId','id');
    }
}

class TypeBottle extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function bottle()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bottle::class,'TypeId','id');
    }
}
```

already try using [Laravel 6 - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException Call to undefined relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480919/laravel-6-illuminate-database-eloquent-relationnotfoundexception-call-to-undef#new-answer?newreg=d9514acf03b84d9d998451758b15e0c7)
and following recomendation from https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#copying-files-and-directories

Comment: Can you add the error. on your code

Comment: how does you Bottle and TypeBottle migrations look like?